Applescript : get hyperlink of cell associated
I  encountering an error when trying to access the hyperlink of a cell in my Numbers spreadsheet using AppleScript. The error message

"Impossible de convertir hyperlink of cell..."

What is correct syntax?
 set value of cell ("B" & 2 ) to newValue
 log "La cellule affiche texte wo URL "


But error with
-- set hyperlinkURL to URL of cell ("B" & 2)  -- ??
-- set myLink to hyperlink of cell ("B" & 2)  -- ??
Is this only possible from application in graphical mode or can I hope to reach the url with applescript
Unable to convert to csv, links do not appear there
Cordialement
on replaceLinksInNumbers(filePath)
    tell application "Numbers"
        set theDocument to open filePath
        tell theDocument
            tell sheet 1
                tell table 1
                    repeat with i from 2 to count of rows -- Commence à la deuxième rangée pour éviter les en-têtes
                        set cellValue to value of cell ("B" & i)
                        if cellValue contains "mathilde.local" then
                            set newValue to my replaceText(cellValue, "http://mathilde.local/", "http://mathilde.local/") -- "https://mathilde.dhenin.fr/")
                            set value of cell ("B" & i) to newValue
                            log "La cellule affiche une url"
                        end if
                        -- set hyperlinkURL to URL of cell ("B" & 2)
                        -- set myLink to hyperlink of cell ("B" & 2)
                        
                        
                        -- set cellValue to value of cell ("B" & i)
                        -- set hyperlinkAddress to address of hyperlink of cell ("B" & i)
                        -- log "URL trouvée dans la cellule B" & i & ": " & hyperlinkAddress
                        
                        -- log hyperlinkURL
                        
                    end repeat
                    set myURL to "https://algotaf.dhenin.fr"
                    
                    -- set value of cell ("B" & 5)  to "=hyperlink(\"" & myURL & "\")"
                    --  set value of cell ("B" & 5) to myURL
                    
                end tell
            end tell
            save
            close saving yes
        end tell
    end tell
end replaceLinksInNumbers

on replaceText(theText, searchString, replaceString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to searchString
    set theTextItems to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replaceString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end replaceText

set filePath to "/Users/dhenin/Desktop/14_Travaux_en_cours/Chantier_Hermes/HermesTpe.numbers"
replaceLinksInNumbers(filePath)

